# CSS is a problem. The element itself assigns a value

Tags: css

I have the following code that calls chat:

```
<div id="chatContainer">
  <span id="chatClose" class="chat-close"></span>
  <div id="chatHeader" >Chat</div>
  <p style="font-size: 15px;padding: 8px;color:white;">
    <b>
      <img src="frontend/chat/img/Chat.png" style="width: 36px;" />
      Chat
    </b>
  </p>
  <div id="chatScroll" style="overflow-y: scroll;">
    <div id="messages"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

But the problem is the following, it is not clear for what reason the chat itself sets a height of 937 pixels. If i look at the source code, and go into the elements and select the chat call, he writes:

```
element.style {
    height: 937px;
    display: block;
}
```

I checked the CSS conflicts and rechecked the pixels, nowhere I set 937 pixels. I tried changing the height, for example by setting 700 pixels:

```
<div id="chatContainer" style="height: 700px;">
```

and it's not help.

My class chatContainer also look's like this:

```
#chatContainer {
    width: 250px;
    z-index: 50;
    position: absolute;
    top: 72px;
    right: 17px;
    bottom: 73px;
    padding-top: 0px;
    background-color: #212F35;
    border-left: 1px solid #2a2a2a;
    border-right: 1px solid #2a2a2a;
    display: none;
    overflow: hidden;
    position:fixed;
}
```

Also i try to add height in `#chatContainer`, it's don't help. How i can remove this problem?

**UPD:** i have a function to tooggle chat. If i remove tooggle from JS, all good, height is what i type. But if i go back tooggle function, all crash...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you see `element.style` inside chrome debug tools, that means its an 'inline style', and usually they're assigned automatically by scripts.

This is an inline style:

```
<div style="height: 100px;"></div>
```

A lot of scripts (javascript) will dynamically size html dom elements based on certain conditions.

So you would want to look at the library and see if they have specific options to see how to specify width and height.

If theres no way to do it, you can override it using `!important`, although this is usually frowned upon because you're not fixing the problem, you're just adding a bandaid over-top of it, which can come back to bite you later:

```
#chatContainer {
  height: 700px !important;
}
```

The reason it's not working is because if you have the same level of styling for a `div`, and its specified in a different locations, they have different priorities. Here are the priorities from most "powerful" to least:

1. inline style (using `style=""` attribute)
2. embedded style (using a `<style>` tag)
3. linked style (using a `<link>` tag)

In other words, if all 3 of those locations target `.some-div {}`, then #1 will always override 2 and 3.

Comment: No it should work fine. You do have conflicting css rules (absolute and fixed) etc, but it will still work fine.

Comment: Remember to mark the answer as chosen if it helped you, cheers!